# Posterior predictive distribution in Gelman's book

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

I don't see how Gelman gets the equality $\int p(\tilde{y},\theta\mid y)d\theta=\int p(\tilde{y}|\theta,y)p(\theta\mid y)d\theta$. Can someone clarify this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem). Rearranging might make it more clear...

$$
p(\tilde{y}|\theta, y) = \frac{p(\tilde{y}, \theta|y)}{p(\theta|y)}
$$

Comment: Oh whoops. That was dumb of me. Thanks.

Comment: @thegamer Glad I could help.

Comment: Wait but wouldn't Baye's theorem indicate that the right hand side equals $p(\tilde{y}\mid(\theta\mid y))$? Why is that equal to $p(\tilde{y}\mid \theta,y)$?

Comment: No,  $$P(A|B, C) = \frac{P(A, B | C)}{P(B|C)}.$$ Does that help? Just ignore the fact that everything is conditioned on $y$ in your case.

Comment: Okay, I think it makes sense now. I guess I'm still just not comfortable with joint distributions yet, which is causing me some confusion.